# How to access pop up digital certificate A1 - Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, undetected-chromedriver

I am creating a website automation for acess E-CAC,  but I can't select the digital certificate when logging into the site.

I'm a programming beginner

my code:

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

def ecac():
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.headless = False
    driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)
    driver.get("https://cav.receita.fazenda.gov.br/autenticacao/login")

    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="login-dados-certificado"]/p[2]/input').click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(20)
    time.sleep(3)

    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="cert-digital"]/a').click()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
       ecac()
```

image
[enter image description here][1]

how to access this pop up and log in to the site?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkKwr.png

Answer (score 0):

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
driver.get("https://cav.receita.fazenda.gov.br/autenticacao/login")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="login-dados-certificado"]/p[2]/input'))).click()
wait.until(EC.alert_is_present())
driver.switch_to.alert.accept()
```

If it's an alert you could wait for it and accept it.